# Should you make objects are generic as possible when planning out architecture?

Tags: programming-practices

I'm trying to improve my skills in planning out clean, modular projects with minimal coupling. Is it best to keep objects as generic as possible?

If so, are there any pitfalls I should try and avoid when designing architecture?

Comment: I think when starting you should do everything as specific as possible. And later when you have "whole picture" you can introduce generic types where they needed

Comment: Clean, modular projects with minimal coupling has little to do with genericity.  If anything, the opposite is probably true.

Comment: What details do you think are most @Robert Harvey?

Comment: The ones that fulfill your software's functional and non-functional requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making every object generic is foolish.

Making every object specific is foolish.

Every object should have a name that ensures that what is found inside is not a surprise. It should make clear what belongs inside it and what belongs outside. Otherwise someone will fill it with clutter. The inside should look like your silverware drawer. Not your junk drawer. It may accept multiple messages (have many methods) but it's work should focus on one idea. It should have a single responsibility. It should be the one and only place you need to make changes when changing the one design decision it addresses.

How generic or specific it should be depends on how far it is from inputs or outputs. Everything close to any kind of IO (file, DB, GUI, web, controls, etc)   will have to be specific and will change often. Anything far from IO and close to high level policy will be more generic and stable.

Be willing to stay specific by ignoring cases that can be put off into different sibling objects that can stand in for this one, rather than over design the current one to handle every case.

Be willing to stay generic by pushing responsibly to deal with kinds of cases completely out the object and onto collaborators that can deal with them without making this object deal with their details.

So how to know when it's too much?

When the objects duties become unclear. Use of the object should be obvious.  If half of the object is at one level of abstraction and the other half at another then a tendency will develop to surround it's use with extra logic, keeping it on life support. When the object is well designed, the using code will be simple and clean.

Always look at how an object will be used. I often design by writing the using code first. Do this and controlling how abstract it is will fall out naturally.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You seem to have a solid grasp on design. Would you be able share any resource recommendations I can study in my own? I'm familiar with SOLID principle and basic design patterns.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by generic.

If you mean generic as “can handle anything”, then no. Especially during the design phase, you don’t know how things are going to change. And that’s fine, just don’t try to solve all of those problems *now*.

If you mean generic as “does one thing, ignoring context”, then yes (with moderation). If you have something that works with text in a file, maybe don’t tie it to a specific file path. Maybe don’t even tie it to files at all if all the thing really needs is text.

It’s all about anticipating **likely** change and accounting for it. You don’t have to *fix* problems that don’t exist yet, but it’s usually worthwhile to spend a little bit of time now so your hands aren’t tied when you finally find out how things need to change.